# jxls forEach tag : how to define local variables?

Tags: jxl

Can we define local variables in jxls which can be used to set an incrementing count for a column.

For eg: Consider the following

```
<jx:forEach items="${myList}" var="myVar">
-- i need to define a local integer variable here which will have an initial value as 0
-- and i will increment it and display in the output xls's first column
</jx:forEach>
```

Basically my requirement is to have somekind of local variable declaration in jxls code which i would increment and display in xml.

Any other alternatives are welcome.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Figured it out.... We can use `<jx:out expr="hssfRow.getRowNum()" />` in the column where we want to display the numbering. We can keep the above piece of code inside <jx:forEach items="${myList}" var="myVar"> tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jx:forEach tag support **varStatus** attribute which defines a name of loop status object which will be passed into bean context for each iteration. The loop status object is an instance of LoopStatus class which has single '**index**' property identifying the index of the current item in the collection being iterated

```
<jx:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee" varStatus="status">
  | ${status.index} | ${employee.name} | ${employee.payment} | ${employee.bonus}
</jx:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.... We can use `<jx:out expr="hssfRow.getRowNum()" />` in the column where we want to display the numbering. We can keep the above piece of code inside `<jx:forEach items="${myList}" var="myVar">` tag